# Angular 2 register service in the root module

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Im relatively new in angular 2 but loving it so far :).

When I register my injectable service on the root module level, im getting no provider error message :`core.umd.js:3491 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: EXCEPTION: No provider for DemoService!`

But when I register the same service in the root component or even in a different **imported** module everything is working fine.

Did I miss something or maybe angular 2 dose not support injectables on the root module ?
Anyway is there a way to overcome this because I need this service to be injected in my router guard class (the canAtivate property on the routing definitions).

---

Here is an example code Im using :
DemoService.ts :

```
@Injectable()
export class DemoService {
}
```

app.ts:

```
import { Component  } from '@angular/core';
import { DemoService } from '../Services/DemoService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
   // providers: [DemoService], // if I will uncomment this line it will work but I want to register the serivce on the root module level !!
    templateUrl: 'Templates/app.html'

})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private dSrv: DemoService) { }

   public name : string  = 'Angular !';
   public desc: string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas risus elit, iaculis quis facilisis id, convallis at mauris. Nunc nisl magna, posuere sit amet ligula viverra, commodo fermentum dolor. Nunc et elit elementum nisi imperdiet venenatis. Proin eu tellus vulputate, tincidunt sem et, semper est. Maecenas volutpat pulvinar nibh non malesuada. Aliquam ex augue, suscipit ut tempor ac, eleifend vitae dolor. Nam scelerisque arcu ligula, id aliquet arcu dignissim sed. Nullam malesuada odio eget justo venenatis laoreet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin malesuada, nunc non porta rhoncus, nibh sapien efficitur velit, sit amet tempor metus quam quis mauris. Proin condimentum non lacus sed rhoncus.';
   public arrValues: Array<any> = [];
```

Module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { WSCommonModule } from '../../common/Common-Module'
import { AppComponent } from './components/app';
import { DemoService } from './Services/DemoService';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, WSCommonModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [DemoService], // this line isnt working
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: share you service code please and where are you using it

Comment: I added a demo code to the Question.

Comment: Hi As I can see you have only one module that is AppModule.ts . In the new version os angular 2 you dont have to provide service to each component but you provide it to the module where components are declared . in youe case you need to add it in Appmodule.ts file and then use constructor injection as you already doing to allow angular to inject .  You can use like this  providers: [ // put all your services here
       DemoService,
    ],  . If this is not working than please chack you version and update it to latest .

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what is missing ?
Mu angular version is 2.4 and I did register my DemoService in the module
`providers: [DemoService], // this line isnt working`.

can you please provide me an example ?

Comment: so I i understand correctly . You adding providers for this service in both module.ts and appcomponent.ts ?

Comment: please check my answer .

Comment: No, i'm trying to add the service **only** on the module.ts.
I comment out the line on the app.ts.
this way it dosn't work :( .
When I uncomment  the line in the app.ts file it dose work, but then the service is register on the component level and no on the module level.

Answer (score 0):

```
    -----------------app.module.ts---------------

    please ingore imports focus on LoginService it is in providers .-- in order to use it in app.component you just need to import it and inject it in the constructor of appcomponent class as show below

    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
    import { routing,    appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
    import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './pagenotfound.component';
    import { MileStoneModule }         from './milestone/milestone.module';
    import { RecepientModule }         from './recepient/routing.module';
    import { InformationRequestModule} from './informationrequest/informationrequest.module';
    import {CustomCommonModule} from './common/common.module';
    import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
    import {AppRecepientService} from './app.static.service';
    import {LoginService} from './login.service';
    import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';
    import { DatepickerModule } from 'angular2-material-datepicker';
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            routing,LoginModule,
            MileStoneModule, RecepientModule,InformationRequestModule,
            HttpModule,
            JsonpModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule
            ,CustomCommonModule,
             MaterialModule.forRoot(),
             DatepickerModule
        ],
        declarations: [AppComponent,
            PageNotFoundComponent,
        ],
        providers: [
            appRoutingProviders , AppRecepientService , LoginService
        ],
       exports:[],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }


    ---- app.component.ts ----------------

    import { Component ,  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {LoginService} from './login.service';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent   implements OnInit  {
      title = 'ControlSubmissionClient';
      totalMileStones = 0;
     totalRecepients = 2;
     isLoggedIn: string;

      constructor (
        private service:  LoginService
        )
      {
    /* this.service.currentUser.subscribe((val) => {
       this.isLoggedIn = val;
          console.log(val);
        });*/

      }
       ngOnInit() {
            console.log('init');
        }
        /*onLogin() {
           //console.log('onLogin from appcpomp');
           //this.service.broadcastTextChange("newuser");
      }*/
      /*private loginSuccess(res: string) {
       // this.isLoggedIn  = "yashn";
      }*/
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
I dont understand Im doing the same thing (just with a different names) but it dosn't work for me.

Comment: Also please check the version of angular previous versions support providers inside component and new version support it on modules

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the AppModule in app.ts like below

```
import { AppModule } from './module';
```